# Catch a referenceError in js

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I have a textarea where user can enter javascript code which upon press of the button would be passed to eval().

I am having trouble catching the referenceError for cases when a user enters something like this:

```
var myName = Maria;
```

instead of

```
var myName = "Maria";
```

Thank you for you time!

Comment: An user entered value is always a string.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ _user can enter javascript code which upon press of the button would be **passed to eval()**._

Comment: You need to be **VERY CAREFUL** with `eval()` and executing user code in the browser, please make sure you know what you're doing before using anything like this in production

Comment: You have misunderstood me - user does not just enter the name, but the entire js line i.e. var myName = ... which then gets executed in js via eval(), so user can pass anything. So when a user forgets quotes around the string, js throws referenceError which i need to catch because I want to code to continue running and give user feedback.

Comment: For those concerned, I am well aware of the risks related to eval()

Comment: @Grundy Your guess is true. OP is evaluating JS only :)

Comment: @leemo OP evaluating Javascript. No other option probably.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, as you said you understood the pit's of `eval()`, here i'm proposing a solution.

```
try {
    var myName = Maria;
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
        // Handle error as necessary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try putting a [try/catch block](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp) around the eval() call. Like this:

```
try {
    eval(userInput);
} catch (e) {
    // do something
}
```

(Note that passing user input to eval() is **NOT** something you should do on a real site, for security reasons.)